# Hardhat Lottery test is failing

Tags: hardhat, chai, chainlink-vrf

```
const { deployments, getNamedAccounts, ethers, network } = require("hardhat")
const { assert, expect } = require("chai")

const {
  developmentChains,
  networkConfig,
} = require("../../helper-hardhat-config.js")


developmentChains.includes(network.name)
  ? describe("Lottery", async function () {
      let lottery, vrfCoordinatorV2Mock, deployer, lotteryEnterenceFee, interval
      const chainId = network.config.chainId

      beforeEach(async function () {
        deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer
        await deployments.fixture(["all"])
        lottery = await ethers.getContract("Lottery", deployer)
        vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract(
          "VRFCoordinatorV2Mock",
          deployer
        )
        lotteryEnterenceFee = await lottery.getEnterenceFee()
        interval = await lottery.getInterval()
      })
      describe("enterRaffle", async function () {
        it("doesn't allow enterence when lottery is calculating...  ", async function () {
          await lottery.enterLottery({ value: lotteryEnterenceFee })
          await network.provider.request({
            method: "evm_increaseTime",
            params: [interval.toNumber() + 1],
          })
          await network.provider.request({
            method: "evm_mine",
            params: [],
          })
          await lottery.performUpkeep([])

          const getState = await lottery.getLotteryState()
          console.log(getState)
          await expect(lottery.enterLottery({ value: lotteryEnterenceFee })).to.be.reverted
        })
      })
    })
  : describe.skip
```

**Error:** 1 failing

1. Lottery
   enterRaffle
   doesn't allow enterence when lottery is calculating...  :
   Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with custom error 'InvalidConsumer()'
   at VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.onlyValidConsumer (@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/mocks/VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol:72)
   at VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.requestRandomWords (@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/mocks/VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol:147)
   at Lottery.performUpkeep (contracts/Lottery.sol:135)
   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
   at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
   at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
   at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
   at HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\node.ts:1819:23)
   at HardhatNode.mineBlock (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\node.ts:508:16)
   at EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\modules\eth.ts:1522:18)

I am not able to figure out what mistake I am making. Can someone help me out with this bug?

Comment: Check VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol, line no. 72

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out if you are running with same error:
https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-js/discussions/1565

Your just need to install `@chainlink/contracts` by running:

```
npm install --save-dev @chainlink/contracts@0.4.1
```